# preg_match_all doesn't reply matches array?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a problem with preg_match_all. 
While preg_match does reply the whole match as the first element of the array, preg_match_all doesn't - the first array is empty. 
At least with the pattern I chose (havn't tried others since it's the one I need) it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
preg_match_all("/<\?\?(\t| )?translate(\t| )?;(\t| )?(.*)(\t| )?\?\?>/U", $file, $translate_info);
```

The pattern itself is working and producing subpattern matches.

Comment: Can you post the data you're trying to match against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated according to new given details :

```
$file = '<?? translate ; foo bar??>';
$res = preg_match_all('/<\?\?(\t| )?translate(\t| )?;(\t| )?(.*)(\t| )?\?\?>/U', $file, $translate_info);
echo "res='$res'\n";
var_dump($translate_info);
```

Works for me, it gives :

```
res='1'
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) "<?? translate ; foo bar??>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) " "
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) " "
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) " foo bar"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Comment: if I do that it doesn't find things anymore. 
If I escape them once it's just the same. 
I search for <??translate bla??> or <?? translate bla?? >

Comment: Omg, im stupid, <?? tags dont show in firefox. Thats why i thought it would not work, thanky you!